# Linux command line tool to count non-empty pages in a PDF file

Tags: linux, pdf, command-line

With `pdfinfo`, I can easily count the number of pages in a PDF file, but that includes empty pages, e.g. before a chapter. What if I want the count of all non-empty packages – is there a tool for that?

Comment: Pages that seem to be empty when looked at by a human, may not be empty when looked at by a machine. Many PDF producers try to avoid adding empty pages: they make sure it doesn't happen by accident. When it is necessary to add an empty page, they usually add something to the empty page (could be anything; there's no standard way of doing this). That makes it very hard for software to detect empty pages. You'd need to *render* each page and then check if there are no visible elements. That costs a lot of CPU.

Answer (score 2):

If by "empty page" you mean: when printed, it wouldn't cause any toner/ink marks on the page, you could use Ghostscript's new `inkcov` device which reports the ink coverage for each page. *(It may be a bit slow to report final results; that is because it needs to virtually render each page in order to compute the ink coverage)*:

Example command:

```
$> gs -o -  -sDEVICE=inkcov sample2.pdf

Processing pages 1 through 8.
Page 1
 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.02231 CMYK OK
Page 2
 0.02363  0.02363  0.02363  0.02363 CMYK OK
Page 3
 0.02527  0.02527  0.02527  0.00000 CMYK OK
Page 4
 0.03322  0.03322  0.03322  0.03322 CMYK OK
Page 5
 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.03413 CMYK OK
Page 6
 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.01984 CMYK OK
Page 7
 0.13274  0.13274  0.13274  0.03355 CMYK OK
Page 8
 0.00000  0.00000  0.00000  0.00000 CMYK OK
```

The values are integers in the range from `0..1`, where a value of 1 represents a 100% ink coverage (for all pixels on the page). The above result hence means:

> *Page 8, when rendered, does not use any ink, hence it is "blank".*

This does not mean that this page is ***really*** empty, when looked at in a PDF viewer. To list but only two examples:

1. It could use white text on a white background, and this text could be highlighted and copy'n'pasted when the PDF is displayed on screen. A printout however would not show anything.
2. The page could be containing "layers" (or *"Optional Content Groups"*, `/OCG` elements), where one layer is set to be displayed on screen, but another (empty) layer is set to be used when printing.